# How to invoke reflected method via a Task in C#?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have some C# code that is running some methods using Reflection. That code looks like this:

```
MyClass myClass = InitializeMyClass();

string[] methods = GetMethodsToRun();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
  MethodInfo m = myClass.GetType().GetMethod(method);
  m.Invoke(myClass, null);  
}
```

This code works. However, I need to run these methods in parallel. For that reason, I've been looking at the Task Parallel Library. In order to run methods in parallel via the Task Parallel Library, I need to create `Task` instances for each method. In an attempt to do this, I've updated the code above to this:

```
MyClass myClass = InitializeMyClass();

string[] methods = GetMethodsToRun();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
  MethodInfo m = myClass.GetType().GetMethod(method);
  Task<object> task = Task.Run<object>(method.Invoke(myClass, null));
}
```

However, this won't work because method.Inkove returns an `object`. I thought by using `.Run<object>` that was communicating the return type of the code I want to run. Still, I receive a compile time error that says:

*Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Func'*

All of a sudden, I feel like I'm making this too difficult. My question is, how do I invoke reflected methods as a Task via C#?

Thank you

Comment: `Task.Run<object>(() => method.Invoke(myClass, null))`

Comment: The usual way is using Lambda Expression/Anonymous Functions. You effectively make one function around each and every method. Of course as it seems those functions seem to a have limited Signatures, I have to wonder why you restort to reflection rather then using some basic inheritance in the first place

Comment: Are you looking to consume the result of the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyClass myClass = InitializeMyClass();

string[] methods = GetMethodsToRun();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
  MethodInfo m = myClass.GetType().GetMethod(method);
  Task.Run(() =>  m.Invoke(myClass, null));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the signature of the method you are using:

```
public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> function);
```

If you notice, the generic type is that of the result, while the parameter for the call is a function that returns the result.

So, based on your code, you need a function that returns type `object` as a result:

```
Task<object> task = Task.Run<object>(
     () => 
     { 
         return m.Invoke(myClass, null); //returns object
     });
```

You can then consume the result with a continuation:

```
 task.ContinueWith(
    (o) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.Result); //Result contains the actual result of the method call.
    });
```

In both cases, we have defined anonymous functions with lambda expressions. It doesn't have to be that way. You can just as well provide your own functions:

```
task.ContinueWith(WriteObject);

private void WriteObject(Task<object> o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Run()` takes a `System.Func<TResult>` (or `System.Action`) delecate.

Your code calls the function immediately, then passes its result (which is not a delegate) to `Task.Run()`.  That won't work.

Instead, you need to call `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` to create a delegate of the right type (which will depend on the return type of the method) that points to the `MethodInfo` (with your instance), cast that to `Func<T>` or `Action`, then pass it to `Task.Run()`.